# Applying a function to only part of a Pandas Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date        Last
2016-11-03  101.58  
2016-11-04  100.50  
2016-11-07  103.55  
2016-11-08  104.63  
2016-11-09  106.15  
2016-11-10  107.65  
2016-11-11  106.74  
2016-11-14  108.22  
2016-11-15  107.92  
2016-11-16  106.03
```

and a simple function:

```
def new_def(x):
    add=70.00
    return x[0]+add
```

I want to add another column to the dataframe using the function, but I only want to apply it to dates prior to '2016-11-09'. I've tried doing this with:

```
df['New']= df[:'2016-11-09'].apply(new_def, axis=1)
```

The resulting column is correct up to '2016-11-09' and NaN afterwards. Any suggestions on how to return 'x[0] + add' prior to '2016-11-09' and 'x[0]' afterwards?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your Date a column or is it the index, it looks like it's the index

Comment: sorry I should have been clearer, yes the Date is the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your `new_def` function to take a date parameter:

```
def new_def(val, date):
    return val+70.0 if date < pd.datetime(2016, 11, 9) else val
```

And then apply it like this:

```
df.apply(lambda r: newdef(r['Last'], r.name), 1)
```

Comment: Yes, it will. I edited the example above to pull the date from the index, not a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["test"]=df.apply(lambda r: r["Last"]+70.0 if pd.datetime.strptime(r.name, "%Y-%m-%d") < pd.datetime(2016, 11, 9) else r["Last"], 1)
```